# Reverse Map Foreign Key in Spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables

Table1
I have two tables

**Cat**

| Id | Name | Owner_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |

**Owner**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cat")
class Cat {
       @Id
       private Long id;
       
       private Sting Name;
       
       @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
       @OneToOne
       private Onwner owner;
    }
    
@Entity
@Table(name="owner")    
class Owner {
      @Id
       private Long id;
    
       private Sting Name;
    }
```

Now when fetching cat I will have the Owner object. My question is is it possible to get the field cat added in Owner so that when querying owner will get Cat also.

```
class Owner {
      @Id
       private Long id;
    
       private Sting Name;

       private Cat cat; /// Like this
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can - also I suggest reading up about different relationship types in the documentation - lots of different annotations to use.

For a bidirectional relationship, you need to also outline the OneToOne relationship on your Owner entity - changing the join parameter to mappedBy

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "owner")
private Cat cat;
```